# Gauss Law in infinite slab

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, gauss-law, vector-fields

When applying Gauss law inside an infinite slab of mass density $\rho$, why can we ignore the mass outside of a symmetric Gaussian surface within the mass? E.g. a rectangular box.

I understand that Gauss law specifically talks about the mass enclosed, but for the infinite slab the mass distribution outside does not cancel by symmetry, and thus should be accounted for?

Comment: What makes you think Gauss law "specifically talks about the mass enclosed:? Gauss law talks about the net charge enclosed by the surface.

Comment: @BobD G’s law applied to gravity would refer to mass not charge enclosed.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand the difference (besides charge/mass). I’m talking about a gravitational system, is that the point of confusion?

Comment: @JakeRose Yes, it was for me, I thought you were talking about Gauss law as it relates to electric flux.

Comment: Same law, different constants...

Comment: What exactly is the statement of Gauss law with respect to a gravitational system. I never heard of it. Are we talking about the gravitational field flux?

Comment: Never mind. I looked it up.

Comment: $\int_{S} \vec{g} \dot \vec{dS} = 4 \pi G M_{enclosed}$

Answer (score 1):

For an infinite sheet of mass the field produced is uniform (going away in both directions).  In order to maintain symmetry within a slab, the two Gaussian surfaces must be equidistant from the center of the slab.  The fields from outside will enter at one surface and leave at the other, contributing nothing to the flux (out).

Answer (score 0):

As We know Gauss's Law is given by 
$$\Phi=\iint _S \mathbf{E}.d\mathbf{A} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$ 
It mainly talk about the net flux (Total flux pass through the surface).In case of infinite slab When you take a slab within the slab ,The net flux is only due to density inside the slab ,the field line due to outer density come in from onside and get out from other and Thus contribute nothing to net flux.That's why we don't conside that outer density.

Answer (score 0):

As with an infinite electric slab, the field produced by a slice of the slab is independent of distance from that slice. As you move away from an infinite plane of charge (electric or mass, anything with $F\propto \frac{1}{r^2}$), you get more outward components from the far-off charges, which balances the fact that the outward force of the charges below you is lessening.

This means that the field from any slice of the slab will have an equal value at both sides of the Gaussian surface, and (as Sahu and Bird mentioned) will not contribute to total flux.